# replace a word in text with javascript but not if the word is in a bigger word.

Tags: javascript, regex, text, replace

Hi I want to replace words in a text string, but this seems harder than I thought. It should be in javascript. Say my word is 'ion'. It should replace when I see in the text: my ion, "ion", ion: is cool, (ion), [ion]. But not when it is part of another word like position (positION).

Probably it should be done with regular expressions but I don't know how.

Comment: Use word boundaries: `\bion\b`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/(\bion\b)/gi`

```
\b    assert position at a word boundary
i     modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
g     modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

parenthesis is used to group the match that can be retried from index 1.

Here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mM8fF9/1)

---

Sample code: (*No need to group it if you just want to replace it*)

```
str.replace(/\bion\b/gi, "XYZ");
```

Comment: You don't need the grouping. With a replace it could look like this: str.replace(/\bion\b/gi, "REPLACE");

Comment: If OP is interested to get the matched group then `()` is needed but not for grouping. Yes your are right @morja Thanks.

Comment: I have already up-voted the comment. @AvinashRaj There is one thing that is missing `gi` that is needed for global search along with ignore case.

Answer (score 0):

You may craft regexp which will tell something like: [not a letter]ion[not a letter].

This would look like: `[^a-zA-Z]ion[^a-zA-Z]`

EDIT:

To keep surrounding characters you need to use placeholders. So the final solution will look like: `str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z])ion([^a-zA-Z])/g, '$1REPLACED$2')`
*REPLACED* is obviously the word you would like replace with.

Comment: This will not match (ion), [ion]